# Make a batch that copies the front end for every user

Tags: batch-file, ms-access-2010

Im not used to working in batch. I've made a database with back end and a light frontend(1mb). This front end gets updated many times so i was trying to make a batch for the users that functions as a shortcut. It should make a copy of the newest frontend save it to a subfolder and name it with the username, then open that copy.
If the user copy already exists it should just open it again.
 So far  i got a batch like this but it doesnt work:

```
if exist "H:\Database\AccountDb\%USERNAME%.accde" (
    start "H:\Database\AccountDb\%USERNAME%.accde" /f /s /q
) else (
    xcopy "H:\Database\frontend.accde" H:\Database\AccountDb\%USERNAME%.accde" /t /e /i /y
    start "H:\Database\AccountDb\%USERNAME%.accde" /f /s /q
)
```

Comment: Keep the `"H:\Database\AccountDb\%USERNAME%.accde"` syntax instead of `"H:\Database\AccountDb\%USERNAME%".accde`. And read output from `start /?` launched from `cmd` shell (i.e. command line window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to START is treated as the window title if it is quoted. You simply need to add an empty title argument when the command must be quoted.

Also, having quotes in the middle of the path is OK, but it doesn't look particularly good. Most people put quotes around the entire path.

```
start "" "H:\Database\AccountDb\%USERNAME%.accde" /f /s /q
```

Comment: It worked indeed. I had too delete the /f /s /q too because these options are not available in access